# Laravel 4 blade remove tabs

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm looking for a *simple stupid* solution, to **remove tabs** (whitespaces) from text within Blade templates.

This will *trim* out all tabs from a string:

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\t/g', '', $string));
```

How should I implement the extension with `Blade::extend()` to achieve this function?

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
@untab
<pre>
    $ curl -i https://api.stackoverflow.com
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
</pre>
@enduntab
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how *simple stupid* you want it to be - but you could just use a HTML Minifer package that does all the hard work for you

https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-HTMLMin